# How to exclude an url-pattern from servlet-mapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have two servlet mapping. All requests will go to spring-ws. That is fine, But except that i want to exclude /legalfollowupnotificationservice/*

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/lglnotificationservice/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You could just let the excluded mapping throw a 404 or standard error.

Answer (score 0):

I handle this problem. I always had correct two servlet-mapping. All my definition od servlet mapping is correct.

But I had a mistake When I defined sws:dynamic-wsdl

```
  <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="lglNotificationWs" portTypeName="LegalFollowUp"
    locationUri="/lglNotificationService/" targetNamespace="http://www.xyz/lglnotificationservice" 
    createSoap11Binding="true" createSoap12Binding="true">
    <sws:xsd location="classpath:/xsd/LegalFollowUpNotificationService.xsd" />
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

lglNotificationService location uri has capital letter and MessageDispatcherServlet is case sensitive.

So my request is correspond to spring-ws byMessageDispatcherServlet and is not correspond to spring-ws2

I handle as using

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/lglNotificationService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```